# Changing url for the content in drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

i want to change the url which am getting  in the drupal show something like this

```
    this is url am getting
     localhost/drupal1/content/article/1

  i want to change like this in the url display..i tried pathauto,urlallias,clean url evrything..but am not getting..
        localhost/drupal1/news-article?nid=1&type=article
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

istall `pathauto` and goto `admin/config/search/path/patterns`, then set this pattern `news-article/&nid=[node:nid]&type=[node:content-type]` to any content type you want

**Note** this is not good idea to change urls to this format

Comment: hi farnabaz..i did what u said..but am not getting special chharacter like ?,= in url..it displaying some hexadecimal value instead of special character like this http://localhost/drupal/content%3F1

Comment: @user3124850 thats because I told it's not good idea,this is not drupal fault, try replacing hexadecimal with special chars and you can see it works fine.